# how to read 100 or more strings per second through py serial port

Tags: python, pyserial, zigbee

**Program to receive data from serial port-**

```
import serial
import time 

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyAM0',
    baudrate=57600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1)

while 1:
    BytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    x = ser.read(BytesToRead)
    print x
```

**Input** - @1,12,5,0:0:1# these types of 100 strings per second
**output** - Mixed data with some data missing and jumbled

**Note** - The strings are received from arduino via zigbee.    What am i doing wrong? Is there any delay problem or I am reading the strings wrongly through the serial port?

Comment: For starter, did u make sure that the Serial settings matches with the one you are receiving from(in your case Arduino, if I understood you well) ?

Comment: yes I have checked them already

Comment: So, you are trying to read data from Arduino? Can u post Arduino's code as well?

Comment: And did you try to communicate with Arduino only (without ZigBee), just to check communication is established properly between them?

Comment: Yes I have checked the communication between them. The problem is that, I am receiving the strings but I can't read them all in a second

Comment: Try to introduce some delay in your while loop, after `print x` add `time.sleep(0.2)`, this will probably give more time to the `ser.inWaiting` to properly read the number of bytes before reading the next.

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any bytes to read, then you shouldn't try to read or print them.

```
while 1:
    BytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    if BytesToRead > 0:
        x = ser.read(BytesToRead)
        print x
```